# Post Request, Returning Undefined, NodeJS, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, postman, body-parser

my post request is returning undefined when I pass a json object to it in the body of a postman request. I have been trying to figure out why this happens, but at the third hour I just can't seem to pin-point what is wrong.

here is the following relevant code:

```
app.post('/api/createBlock', (req, res) =>{
    const { Dblock } = req.body;
    console.log(Dblock);
    //Dblock returning undefined
    //dataBlock.createDB(Dblock);
});
```

and as for postman, this is what I am inserting:
[json object to a post request at the right endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSoML.png)

and here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:174:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:60:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:174:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:60:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Where do you try to access `auth`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am just trying to print out the entire request for debug, but the error persists if I do console.log(Dblock.auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/api/createBlock', (req, res) =>{
  const Dblock = req.body;
  console.log(Dblock);
  //Dblock returning undefined
  //dataBlock.createDB(Dblock);
});
```

Do it in this way, this will solve your problem.

`const { Dblock } = req.body;` Here, your code is looking for a property called `Dblock` in `req.body` which is not available.

To know more about destructuring assignment please, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I didn't take notice that Dblock was not an object, do you mind explaining to me why Dblock wouldn't be an object if it is taking a JSON object?